# Bootstrap 4 border overlapping button element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-4, border

I have the following HTML

```
<h2 class="border-center-right mt-4">
    <span class="bg-white float-left">CREDITCARDNAME</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right">APPLY NOW</button>
</h2>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4. The border is currently overlapping the "Apply Now" button. How can I make it so the border sits behind the button?

[image: bootstrap4]

THANKS!

I added the code to the following Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katzumi/98c5q2cf/

And these are the border styles currently applied to `<h2 class="border-center-right mt-4">`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider adding a fiddle and what you have tried so far so we can help you troubleshooting.

Comment: We don't know what `border-center-right` is applying so it's hard to say... I *can* tell you that specifying `d-inline-block` with `float-left` is superfluous.  `float: left` supersedes `display: inline-block`...

Comment: I added a fiddle and removed the superfluous 'd-inline-block'. I can add more details if needed. Thx!

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't apply the border you're describing so again... how do we troubleshoot that? I *suspect* the border is actually added via a pseudo element whose z-index is higher than the button.

Comment: Sorry about that, @RobertC. I updated the CSS to be SCSS and you can now see the border style (.border-center-right) on line 53. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just remove float-left from your span.

I made the border red so it was easier to see against a white background.

```
<div class="container mb-5">
  <h2 class="border-center-right mt-4" style="border-bottom: 1px solid red;">
    <span class="d-inline-block bg-white">CREDITCARDNAME</span>
    <button type="button" class="d-inline-block btn btn-primary float-right">APPLY NOW</button>
  </h2>

  <div class="text-4-col">

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/98c5q2cf/2/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I reduced the width of the element &::after the border-center-right class.

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .border-center-right {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      height: 1px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      **width: 50%;**
      background: $accent-secondary;
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```